# groupby on subset of a multi index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (*df*) with a multi index consisting of 3 indexes, '*A*', '*B*', and '*C*' say, and I have a column called *Quantity* containing floats.

What I would like to do is perform a groupby on '*A*' and '*B*' summing the values in *Quantity*. How would I do this? The standard way of working does not work because pandas does no recognize the indexes as columns and if I use something like

```
df.groupby(level=0).sum()
```

it seems I can only select a single level. How would one go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple levels like:

```
df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
#alternative
df.groupby(level=['A','B']).sum()
```

Or pass parameter level to `sum`:

```
df.sum(level=[0, 1])
#alternative
df.sum(level=['A','B'])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2,3],
                   'B':[3] * 5,
                   'C':[3,4,5,4,5],
                   'Quantity':[1.0,3,4,5,6]}).set_index(['A','B','C'])
print (df)
       Quantity
A B C          
1 3 3       1.0
    4       3.0
2 3 5       4.0
    4       5.0
3 3 5       6.0

df1 = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
print (df1)
     Quantity
A B          
1 3       4.0
2 3       9.0
3 3       6.0

df1 = df.groupby(level=['A','B']).sum()
print (df1)
     Quantity
A B          
1 3       4.0
2 3       9.0
3 3       6.0
```

---

```
df1 = df.sum(level=[0, 1])
print (df1)
     Quantity
A B          
1 3       4.0
2 3       9.0
3 3       6.0

df1 = df.sum(level=['A','B'])
print (df1)
     Quantity
A B          
1 3       4.0
2 3       9.0
3 3       6.0
```